# Writing and Saving to a PDF with VBA

Tags: vba, pdf, save

I have been able to successfully write to a pdf, but now I am trying to save it.  I know I need to use a pddoc in order to save, but I can't set it to match the avdoc that I use to write to the pdf.  The real code has a lot of fields so I will just reduce that to one field and put what I have below:

```
Sub mysub()
'basic declarations and initializations
Dim myfullpath As String
Dim myField As String 
     myfullpath = "C:\mypdf.pdf"
     myField = "Hello"
 
'pdf overhead declarations and initializations
Dim aApp As Acrobat.AcroApp
Dim av_doc As Acrobat.AcroAVDoc
Dim pdf_form As AFORMAUTLib.AFormApp
     Set aApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
     Set av_doc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
     Set pdf_form = CreateObject("AFORMAUT.App")

     If av_doc.Open(myfullpath, "") = True Then
'declare and initialize pdf fields
     Dim pdfField As AFORMAUTLib.Field
          Set pdfField = pdf_form.Fields("pdfField")

'set value in pdf
          pdfField = myField

'declare and initialize pddoc in order to save
     Dim PdfDoc As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
          Set PdfDoc = av_doc      'having trouble here 
                                   '“Run-time error ‘13’: Type mismatch”
          PdfDoc.Save PDSaveFull, myfullpath
          av_doc.Close False
          Set pdfField = Nothing
     End If
aApp.Exit
Set aApp = Nothing
Set av_doc = Nothing
Set PdfDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/save-adobe-pdf-file-as-pdf/54c5a6d0-304f-4d98-a627-4cb43e1ee895

Comment: After creating my original code, that is where I got some of the code I put in my example.  It didn't work.   You can see in the rest of the thread they still had trouble with it.  I'll try with that again and see if maybe I am missing something from that.

Comment: You were only missing one thing: `Set PdfDoc = av_doc.GetPDDoc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```vb
Sub mysub()
    
    Dim myfullpath As String, myfullpath_edited As String
    Dim myField As String
    Dim aApp As Acrobat.AcroApp
    Dim av_doc As Acrobat.AcroAVDoc
    Dim pdfField As Object 'AFORMAUTLib.Field
    Dim PdfDoc As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
    Dim pdf_form As Object 'AFORMAUTLib.AFormApp
    
    myfullpath = "C:\Tester\mypdf.pdf"
    myfullpath_edited = "C:\Tester\mypdf_edited.pdf"
    myField = "Hello"
     
    Set aApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    Set av_doc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
    Set pdf_form = CreateObject("AFORMAUT.App")
    
    'aApp.Show
    If av_doc.Open(myfullpath, "") Then
        
        'av_doc.BringToFront
        Set pdfField = pdf_form.Fields("pdfField")
        pdfField.Value = myField 'set value in pdf
        
        Set PdfDoc = av_doc.GetPDDoc  '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        PdfDoc.Save PDSaveFull, myfullpath_edited
        av_doc.Close False
                  
    End If
    
    aApp.Exit
    Set aApp = Nothing
    Set av_doc = Nothing
    Set PdfDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: HI Tim! is there possibility of the same `VBA` code working on MAC OS? 
I have similar but it give me error "ActiveX component can't create object" at `Set aApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")`

Comment: I don't have a Mac but I'd guess not.